# How to delete Cassandra snapshots which are older than 1 month

Tags: cassandra

All Cassandra snapshots can be deleted with

`nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 clearsnapshot`

and there is another to delete one specific snapshot.

`nodetool clearsnapshot -t snapshot_name`

However, I would like to delete all snapshots which are created 1 month ago. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not specified a name for the snapshot, the engine will assign by default as name the timestamp, this will be the number of ms from Epoch. One way to achieve this is to calculate what was the epoch time 30 days ago (one month), and any snapshot id that is lower than that number is older than the threshold that you specified.

Another way to do this is to customize the name of the snapshot (`-t`) with the date in a human-readable format, which will make it easier to choose the snapshots to delete.